# Physical meaning of Transpose of an Operator in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, definition

What's the physical meaning of transpose of a matrix in Quantum Mechanics?

Although for Unitary or Orthogonal operators, I know that transpose of that operator would reverse the action and that's because, $A^T=A^{-1}$.

But if the operator is neither orthogonal nor unitary, then in that context what does transpose of an operator means?

*Apart of this interpretation, that Transpose of an operator is equivalent to same operation but in dual space! .*

Comment: No, it has no general physical meaning since it depends on the arbitrary choice of a Hilbert  basis, differently of , e.g., the Hermitian conjugation of operators.

Comment: @Valter Moretti: Technically the Hermitian conjugate is also dependent on a basis, too, as you can see by noting it is a conjugate _transpose_ - it's just that the basis happens to be shipped with the inner product for free :)

Comment: I think you are wrong. The Hermitian conjugate is completely defined by referring to the scalar product of the space and it does not depend on a choice of basis. I mean taking the conjugate transpose with resoect to two different orthonormal based you get the same operator. It does not happen referring to the only conjugate or transpose.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose  a linear map $A:V\to V$ is represented in a basis ${\bf e}_n$ by the  matrix ${A^n}_m$. This means that $A$ maps ${\bf e}_n$ to
$$
A[{\bf e}_n] = {\bf e}_n{A^m}_n.
$$

The map $A$ automatically  induces a "conjugate"  map that is  usually called $A^*$ by functional analysts---  a rather bad notation from the viewpoint of physics   as  no complex conjugation is needed nor implied.   This induced map acts  the dual space $V^*$ consisting of linear functions from ${\bf f}:V\to {\mathbb C}$
by
$$ 
(A^*{\bf f})[{\bf x}] = {\bf f}(A[{\bf x}])
$$

If ${\bf e}^{*n}$ is the set of functions constituting the   dual basis such that ${\bf e}^{*n}[{\bf e}_m]= \delta^n_m$,
then
$$ 
A^* [{\bf e}^{*n}] =   {\bf e}^{*m}{A^n}_m,
$$
so the indices $n$ and $m$ have been interchanged. In other words the matrix representing $A^*$ in the basis ${\bf e}^{*n}$ is the transpose of the matrix representing $A$. As a result of this some linear algebraists call $A^*$ the *transpose* of $A$ and may use the notation $A^T:V^*\to V^*$.

In Dirac notation the original $A$ acts on the space of kets $|n\rangle$ by
$$
A|n\rangle= |m\rangle\langle m|A|n\rangle
$$
and the conjugate map acts on the dual space of bra vectors by
$$
\langle n|A= \langle n|A|m\rangle\langle  m|
$$

In Dirac  notation ${A^n}_m\to  \langle n|A|m\rangle$ so we lose the distiction between upstairs/downstairs indices and so are restricted to orthonormal bases. The equation
$$ 
(A^*{\bf e}^{*m})[{\bf e}_n] = {\bf e}^{*m}(A[{\bf e}_n])
$$
now reads
$$
(\langle m|A)|n\rangle= \langle m|(A|n\rangle)
$$
so Dirac does not need the confusing notation $A^*$, nor does he need an explicit  transpose because the operator is acting to its left rather than to its right.  The operation to the left on the bra is nonetheless the action of the transposed matrix.

As far as I know this story is only consistent intepretation of the transpose in QM.

Answer (score -1):

From a physical point of view, the only relevant operators are those that are "symmetric" (in fact, self-adjoint). These operators have the properties of remaining unchanged under a "transposition". Any other operator that does not satisfy this property is not *observable*.

Having said this, there are some interesting cases, like the one mentioned in the OP, like unitary operators. These can be given the physical meaning of *transformations*, in a rather broad sense. More generally, one can consider more general objects, like partial isometries. A partial isometry $V$ maps a subspace of a Hilbert space into another subspace of the same dimension. Hence, every unitary is a partial isometry, but not every partial isometry is a unitary. If $V$ maps $K$ to $K'$, then it is easy to see that $V^T$ maps $K'$ back to $K$. For any bounded operator $A$ on a Hilbert space, one can find a positive operator $|A|$ and a partial isometry $V$ such that

$$A = V|A|$$

This is known as the *polar decomposition* of $A$. Using this, one then finds

$$A^T = |A|V^T$$

which can help to get an idea of what the transposition is doing on the operator $A$.

Comment: Yes, but the analog in Quantum Mechanics (the OP refers to it) uses the adjoint and not the transpose...

Comment: mutatis mutandis :)